# Is it possible to reverse ng-infinite-scroll in Angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, npm, infinite-scroll, nginfinitescroll

I am new in AngularJs . I have implemented ng-infinite-scroll to show my posts as per it's documentation on [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-infinite-scroll) link.Now scrolling works top to bottom.
But how can I implemented it in reverse order as like chat conversation(bottom to up). 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-infinite-scroll

Comment: There seems to be an issue on the project's github. See https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll/issues/286

Comment: have you any solution ? @ZdenekHatak